# Firefox on i3 - all hieroglyphs

Tags: fonts, firefox, i3

I just ran a system update on my Arch System, after a rather long while. There were some issues with the automatic update for Firefox so I uninstalled it completely and reinstalled it later. Everything else installed without error.

Now I'm experiencing some serious font display issues in Firefox. Parts of web pages appear in some sort of hieroglyphs. If you try to look at the source, all of it is written in these same glyphs. If I were to try to define a rule, I'd say it seems like only monospace fonts are affected.

[image: How Unix SE looks in my browser]
[image: Source code view]

While I know my way around Linux in general, I'm kind of new to the Linux desktop. I'm pretty sure it's a font issue but I wouldn't know where to tweak. All help is appreciated.

**UPDATE** as a reply to the comment:

These are the font settings in Firefox. Changing the monospace font from "monospace" to another monospace font in the list (e.g. Ubuntu Mono), solved the issue. So, which monospace font was Firefox trying to use, and couldn't find, with the default setting?

[image]

Comment: What fonts is firefox using?  `Edit > Preferences > Content > Fonts > Advanced` (notably monospace).  Does the font exist in the list printed by `fc-list`?

Comment: @grochmal Thanks for the pointer. I have updated my question with more info.