# i3 font totally broken

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, i3, bugs

the font on my machine changed almost everywhere out of nowwhere, while i was browsing. it happened ca. half an hour after i've updated my system, now i'm basically unable to do anything.

how can this happen and what can i do to undo this? i've attached a screenshot just for the curious ones
 [image]

I am able to read and edit files by exiting i3, the terminal outside of it works just fine. but when i3 is started, almost everything but text written on webpages appear like that. text on webpages is partly shown like this, partly shown normal, depending on which kind the text is.
I'm using Arch on version 4.7.4-1

Comment: What packages did you update (see `/var/log/pacman.log`)? Maybe reverting one of these updates may track which package introduced the change. Did you had the current pacman version (5.0.1) *prior* to the upgrade? (In case some hook did not run)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was meant as a comment but due to not having 50 reputation I couldn't post it.

I just saw a similar question and thought it might help with this question, if you are using any monospace font that is? In the question linked below it seems to only affect `firefox` but you might want to give it a try.

[Firefox on i3 - all hieroglyphs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305565/firefox-on-i3-all-hieroglyphs)

If that does not work I would suggest you to check `/var/log/pacman.log` and revert any changes related to fonts.

Comment: I've uploaded the file containing the log of the recent update -> http://textuploader.com/dshxf
How can i identify the changes linked to font edits, and how may i revert them afterwards?
I'll also try just to set another font like shown in your link, if this will lead to fix the problem you have my gratitude!

Comment: Did changing font work?

I rushed through the log and could only find three clearly font-related packages, ````fontconfig````, ````gsfonts```` and ````libxfont````. If changing font did not work I would suggest looking into ````gsfonts````.

There's some pretty good info on the wiki regarding this, see [Return to an earlier package version](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/downgrading_packages#Return_to_an_earlier_package_version) and [How to downgrade one package](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Linux_Archive#How_to_downgrade_one_package)

Comment: This one helped to solve the problem! It seems like my standard monospace font was deleted by something (the update maybe, although I'm curious how it was delayed by ~30 minutes after the update finished.)
By setting a new font to everything referring to that font [i3, urxvt and firefox] everything is back to normal now. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that it helped! I have no idea why it was delayed 30 minutes though.